# Python pandas remove part from string after substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to clear wrong text that comes after the "Model" value in the "Name" column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABC-12(s)', 'Some text ABC-12(s) wrong text'], ['ABC-45', 'Other text ABC-45 garbage text'], ['XYZ-LL', 'Another text XYZ-LL unneeded text']], columns = ['Model', 'Name'])
```

| index | Model | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC-12(s) | Some text ABC-12(s) wrong text |
| 1 | ABC-45 | Other text ABC-45 garbage text |
| 2 | XYZ-LL | Another text XYZ-LL unneeded text |

Expected result:

| index | Model | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC-12(s) | Some text ABC-12(s) |
| 1 | ABC-45 | Other text ABC-45 |
| 2 | XYZ-LL | Another text XYZ-LL |

Have tried:

```
df["name"] = df["name"].str.partition(df["model"].to_string(), expand=False)
```

But that gives back the original string without changes or error. Like it could not find the delimiter within the "Name" cell.
Seems like I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does someone knows why the "Have tried" section did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `partition` in a list comprehension and then join the first two parts back.

```
df['name_mod'] = [''.join(name.partition(model)[:-1]) 
                  for name,model in zip(df['Name'], df['Model'])]
```

---

```
       Model                               Name             name_mod
0  ABC-12(s)     Some text ABC-12(s) wrong text  Some text ABC-12(s)
1     ABC-45     Other text ABC-45 garbage text    Other text ABC-45
2     XYZ-LL  Another text XYZ-LL unneeded text  Another text XYZ-LL
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `partition`. Is this the right one? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition

Comment: @merced yes that’s it

Comment: Thank you, this works, however be notified that the XXX in df['XXX'] is case sensitive so if it doesn't work right away check the case.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using re:

```py
import re

df["Name"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: re.split(r"(?<=" + re.escape(x["Model"]) + r")\s*", x["Name"])[0],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Model                 Name
0  ABC-12(s)  Some text ABC-12(s)
1     ABC-45    Other text ABC-45
2     XYZ-LL  Another text XYZ-LL
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!
Preferred the solution without additional module as the regex is well known for not being beginner user friendly.